# What's the best way to listen to NSAttributedString attribute changes in Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

I have a model that is a group of `NSMutableAttributedString`s. Well currently it's a wrapper of a `MyString` class. Each string manages it's own attributes/state.

```swift
typealias NSAttrStringAttr = [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]
typealias MyStringAttribute = (NSAttrStringAttr, NSRange)
class MyString: ObservableObject {
  var attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString
  @Published var attributes: [MyStringAttribute] = []

  init(string: String) {
    self.attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
  }
}
```

The main reason for this is so that I can expose changes in the `NSAttributedString`s attributes, as follows:

```swift
extension MyString {
  func updateAttributes() {
    self.attributes = []
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.attributedString.length - 1)
    attributedString.enumerateAttributes(in: range, using: {(attrs, range, _) in
      self.attributes.append((attrs, range))
    })
  }

  func addAttribute(_ name: NSAttributedString.Key, value: Any, range: NSRange) {
    attributedString.addAttribute(name, value: value, range: range)
    updateAttributes()
  }

  func addAttributes(_ attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [:], range: NSRange) {
    attributedString.addAttributes(attrs, range: range)
    updateAttributes()
  }
}
```

```swift
class MyStringGroup {
  private var: strings: [MyString] = []
  var _attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString
  var attributedString {
    get {
      if let str = _attributedString {
        return str
      } else {
        var newAString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
        strings.forEach { self.newAString.append($0.attributedString) }
        _attributedString = newAString
      }
    }
  }
  var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  func append(_ string: MyString) {
    string.$attributes.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
      // Handle rewriting portion of NSAttributedString based on substring update
    }).store(in: &cancellable)
    strings.append(string
  }

  func someStringUpdate(..., range: NSRange) {
    let str = strings.findRightString(range: range)
    str.someStringUpdate(..., range: offsetRangeForString(str, range: range))
  }
}
```

The main reason for this is that strings are linked with strings outside of the text, and they update certain attributes based on user action, responses from the server, etc. The reason for wrapping `NSAttributedString` is so that the logic for managing string attributes, and their connection to the other text can be managed separately of the entire text, and `MyStringGroup` needs to know if a `MyString` instance has updated its attributes so that it can re-render. I have been trying to use the reactive pattern of `Combine`, but can't find anyway to natively listen to `attribute` changes in `NSAttributedString`, as the only way to access attributes is via function `attributes(at:effectiveRange:)` and `enumerateAttributes(in:using:)`, so currently I'm stuck with wrapping. Is there a better way to propagates changes in the substring/sentence `NSAttributedString` without having to wrap it and rewrite all it's methods?

Comment: You can listen/subscribe only to a **publisher**. If the framework doesn’t provide any, you have to do it. A possible way is to *publish* the changes in the `update` method for example with a `subject`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (somewhat) new [AttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring) struct.

The struct provides a similar API as the `NSMutableAttributedString` one, and what's best is that you can use it as a `@Published` property, which will automatically emit change events when any mutation happens on the attributed string (yes, this includes any attribute changes).

```swift
class MyString: ObservableObject {
    @Published var attributedString: AttributedString
}
```

With this change, you can remove all the boilerplate code that interfaced with the old Foundation class.